# Similarity in formulae for curvatures

Tags: vector-analysis, vectors, curvature

> At each point on a curve $\mathcal{C}$, the tangent vector is parallel
>   to a non-vanishing vector field $\mathbf{F}$. Show that the curvature
>   $\kappa$ of $\mathcal{C}$ is given by:
>   $$\kappa=\frac{|\mathbf{F}\times
>  (\mathbf{F}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{F}|}{|\mathbf{F}|^3}\;\;(1)$$

I have done a similar question before: for a curve $\mathbf{r}(t)$ in the $xy$ plane parametrised by $x(t),y(t):$

$$\kappa=\frac{|\mathbf{r}'\times \mathbf{r}''|}{|\mathbf{r'}|^3}\;\;(2)$$

(I can post the proof if anyone is interested)

Given the similarity, I am wondering whether there might be a very efficient/quick way of getting at $(1)$ by cleverly relating it to $(2)$. Is this feasible? I have tried using the same steps as those used to arrive at $(2)$ but I am unsure even of how the definitions carry over in terms of derivatives... Any form of help is appreciated.

Comment: The similarity is, of course, not by accident. To derive (1) from (2) directly you could try to show that there is a paramitrization of the curve such that the tangent vector is just $F$. You then need to verify that the formulas agree in that case, that is, the derivative of a vector field along the curve agrees with the tangent map of the curve when the vector field coincides with the image of the latter (this may be part of what you covered in your course).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First note that (2) is reparametrization invariant. Thus, wlog,   $\mathcal{C}$ is an integral curve of $\mathbf{F}$, i.e. given by a solution $\mathbf{r}(t)$ of $\mathbf{r}'=\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r})$. Take the derivative of the last equation wrt $t$ (use the chain rule), get $\mathbf{r}''=
 (\mathbf{F}\cdot\nabla)\mathbf{F}$. Plug into (2).

Comment: Thanks for this. When I am taking the derivative $\mathbf{r}''=\mathbf{r}'\frac{d}{d\mathbf{r}}\mathbf{F}(\mathbf{r})$ how do I interpret $\mathbf{F}'?$ (by that I mean, I am not sure how to argue that it is $\mathbf{F}\cdot\nabla).$

Comment: Write everything carefully in coordinates and use the chain rule: ${d\over dt}F_i({\bf r}(t))=\sum_j{\partial F_i\over \partial x_j}{dx_j\over dt}$ etc.